# How can I prevent Matplotlib from cutting off the last bar in a bar chart even if it has a value of zero?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting the signal strengths of some measurements on bar charts. Sometimes a measurement goes wrong and no value is obtained. In those cases, I give the measurement the value 0 or NaN. Both do the job for me. If I plot those measurements and the last measurement happens to be a failed one, Matplotlib cuts the last bar off. For the sake of uniformity, I don't want that to happen. How can I make Matplotlib format the x axis as if the last measurement had a value different from zero?

Picture with an example for the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzFcj.png

The bar chart for Benzene displays the problem. The 6th measurement is cut off. The bar chart for Toluene-d8 displays it "correctly". The red line is just the mean value and not important for this problem.

I tried to change the alignment of the bars from align to edge, but that messed up the axis alignment for the ticks.

Comment: Have you tried setting plt.xlim() or ax.xlim()? [Ref](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html)

Comment: I tried that. It works somewhat but it is very finicky to scale the x axis to match the x axis of a "good" graph. Is there a way to get the xlim of a graph scaled by the algorithm in order to set those lims manually for a "bad" graph?
EDIT: Figured it out myself! I just used ax.get_xlim().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by setting the ax.set_xlim() manually. In order to match the xlim of a "good" graph I got the limits by printing them out with ax.get_xlim().